# The Yaml is not validating If condition: /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 64, Col: 13): Expected at least one key-value pair in the mappin

Tags: azure-devops, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

```yaml
name: $(Version.Major).$(Version.Minor).$(Version.Semantic)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - feature/*
      - bug/*
parameters:
  - name: host
    type: string
    default: IPC_T1_MSG
    values:
      - IPC_T1_MSG
      - IPC_A1_MSG
      - IPC_T4TC_MSG
  - name: checkserver
    displayName: To check the server if it Tomcat
    type: boolean
variables:
  Version.Major: 1
  Version.Minor: 0
  Version.Semantic: '$[counter(variables[''Version.Major''].variables[''Version.Minor''], 2)]'
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildMavenProject
        variables:
          - name: MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER
            value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
          - name: incomingFeedName
            value: P00877-incoming-extralibs
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
             - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
               inputs:
                 artifactsFeeds: $(incomingFeedName)
             - task: Bash@3
               inputs:
                 targetType: inline
                 script: >
                   mvn -f pom.xml help:effective-pom -Doutput=effectivePom

                   cat effectivePom | sed 
                   '/<dependency>/I{:A;N;h;/<\/dependency>/I!{H;bA};/<\/dependency>/I{g;/\b.ing.\b/Id}}'
                   | tr -d " \t\n\r"  |  sed
                   's:</dependencies>:</dependencies>\n:g' |  sed 
                   's:^.*<dependencies>\(.*\)</dependencies>.*$:\1:g'  | sed \$d
                   >mavenCacheKey
               displayName: Generate cache key
             - task: Cache@2
               inputs:
                 key: ./mavenCacheKey
                 path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
                 displayName: Cache Maven
             - task: Maven@3
               inputs:
                 mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                 goals: 'versions:set'
                 options: -X -Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
                   -DnewVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)
               displayName: Set version
               
             - ${{ if contains(parameters.host, '_T1_') }}:  
             - task: Maven@3
               inputs:
                 mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                 mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
                 javaHomeOption: JDKVersion
                 jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
                 jdkArchitectureOption: x64
                 publishJUnitResults: true
                 testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                 goals: package
               displayName: Compile maven project
             - ${{ if contains(parameters.host, '_T4TC_') }}:        
             - task: Maven@4
               inputs:
                 mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                 mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
                 javaHomeOption: JDKVersion
                 jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
                 jdkArchitectureOption: x64
                 publishJUnitResults: true
                 testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                 goals: package
               displayName: Compile maven project            
             - task: CopyFiles@2
               inputs:
                 SourceFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target
                 Contents: '*.jar'
                 TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
               displayName: Stage Jar files for publishing
             - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
               inputs:
                 targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
                 artifact: Binaries
                 publishLocation: pipeline
               displayName: Publish Jar file
  - stage: Deploy_JansTool
    pool: CDaaSLinux
    jobs:
      - job: Deploy_JansTool
        variables:
          KeyVaultSubscription: P00877-KeyVault-SVC-NONPROD
          '${{ if contains(parameters.host, ''_T1_'') }}':
            defaultKeyVaultName: INGOneP00877KvT
            secretsFilter: '*'
            hosts_ini_directory_name: test
            ansible_account: ansible_ibp_test@HG_IAM_00001u7_T@ssz
            CyberAck: P00877-CyberAck-test
          '${{ if contains(parameters.host, ''_A1_'') }}':
            defaultKeyVaultName: INGOneP00877KvA
            secretsFilter: '*'
            hosts_ini_directory_name: accept
            ansible_account: ansible_ibp_acc@HG_IAM_00001u7_A@ssz
            CyberAck: P00877-CyberAck-accept
          '${{ if contains(parameters.host, ''_T4TC_'') }}':
            defaultKeyVaultName: INGOneP00877KvT
            secretsFilter: '*'
            hosts_ini_directory_name: test
            ansible_account: ansible_ibp_test@HG_IAM_00001u7_T@ssz
            CyberAck: P00877-CyberAck-test
            checkserver: true
            
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 1
            persistCredentials: true
          - task: AzureKeyVault@1
            displayName: Loading Default Azure KeyVault
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '${{ variables.KeyVaultSubscription }}'
              KeyVaultName: $(defaultKeyVaultName)
              SecretsFilter: $(secretsFilter)
              RunAsPreJob: true
          - task: CyberArkPwv@1
            displayName: PWV
            name: PWV
            inputs:
              svcConnection: '${{ variables.CyberAck }}'
              accounts: $(ansible_account)
          - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
            displayName: Replace Tokens with KeyVault Secrets
            inputs:
              rootDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/
              targetFiles: |
                **/*.yml
                **/*.ini
              keepToken: true
              enableTelemetry: false
          - task: ING-Romania.CDaaSAnsibleRolesInit.custom-build-release-task.PrepareAnsibleRuntime@0
            displayName: Prepare Ansible Runtime
            inputs:
              ansibleConfigFilePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/ansible.cfg

          - task: Ansible@0
            displayName: execute Deploy_JansToolPB.yml
            inputs:
              ansibleInterface: agentMachine
              playbookPathOnAgentMachine: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/Deploy_JansTool_PB.yml
              inventoriesAgentMachine: file
              inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/ipc/${{variables.hosts_ini_directory_name}}/hosts.ini
              args: '-vvvvv --extra-vars "host=${{parameters.host}}"'
              
          - task: Ansible@0
            displayName: execute Deploy_JansToolPB.yml
            inputs:
              ansibleInterface: agentMachine
              playbookPathOnAgentMachine: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/Deploy_JansTool_PB2.yml
              inventoriesAgentMachine: file
              inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/ipc/${{variables.hosts_ini_directory_name}}/hosts.ini
              args: '-vvvvv --extra-vars "host=${{parameters.host}}"'
```

error line is from below

```yaml
- ${{ if contains(parameters.host, '_T1_') }}:  
             - task: Maven@3
               inputs:
                 mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                 mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
                 javaHomeOption: JDKVersion
                 jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
                 jdkArchitectureOption: x64
                 publishJUnitResults: true
                 testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                 goals: package
               displayName: Compile maven project
             - ${{ if contains(parameters.host, '_T4TC_') }}:        
             - task: Maven@4
               inputs:
                 mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                 mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
                 javaHomeOption: JDKVersion
                 jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
                 jdkArchitectureOption: x64
                 publishJUnitResults: true
                 testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                 goals: package
               displayName: Compile maven project
```

So this is the code sinpped I have used, I do not understand why my If condition is giving me error.

/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 64, Col: 16): Expected at least one key-value pair in the mapping
/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 76, Col: 62): Expected a mapping
/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 76, Col: 16): Expected at least one key-value pair in the mapping

I tried to validate pipeline before triggering the pipeline and it shows me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Checked your YAML sample, the cause of the issue could be that the If expression contains extra single quotes. And the indentation of the task inputs fields have issue.

To solve this issue, you can refer to the following sample:

```
  - ${{ if contains(parameters.host, '_T1_') }}:          
     - task: Maven@3
       inputs:
       mavenPomFile: pom.xml
       mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
       javaHomeOption: JDKVersion
       jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
       jdkArchitectureOption: x64
       publishJUnitResults: true
       testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
       goals: package
```

**Update:**

```
name: $(Version.Major).$(Version.Minor).$(Version.Semantic)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - feature/*
      - bug/*
parameters:
  - name: host
    type: string
    default: IPC_T1_MSG
    values:
      - IPC_T1_MSG
      - IPC_A1_MSG
      - IPC_T4TC_MSG
  - name: checkserver
    displayName: To check the server if it Tomcat
    type: boolean
    default: false
variables:
  Version.Major: 1
  Version.Minor: 0
  Version.Semantic: '$[counter(variables[''Version.Major''].variables[''Version.Minor''], 2)]'
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildMavenProject
        variables:
          - name: MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER
            value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
          - name: incomingFeedName
            value: P00877-incoming-extralibs
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
             - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
               inputs:
                 artifactsFeeds: $(incomingFeedName)
             - task: Bash@3
               inputs:
                 targetType: inline
                 script: >
                   mvn -f pom.xml help:effective-pom -Doutput=effectivePom

                   cat effectivePom | sed 
                   '/<dependency>/I{:A;N;h;/<\/dependency>/I!{H;bA};/<\/dependency>/I{g;/\b.ing.\b/Id}}'
                   | tr -d " \t\n\r"  |  sed
                   's:</dependencies>:</dependencies>\n:g' |  sed 
                   's:^.*<dependencies>\(.*\)</dependencies>.*$:\1:g'  | sed \$d
                   >mavenCacheKey
               displayName: Generate cache key
             - task: Cache@2
               inputs:
                 key: ./mavenCacheKey
                 path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
               displayName: Cache Maven
             - task: Maven@3
               inputs:
                 mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                 goals: 'versions:set'
                 options: -X -Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
                   -DnewVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)
               displayName: Set version
               
             - ${{ if contains(parameters.host, '_T1_') }}:  
               - task: Maven@3
                 inputs:
                  mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                  mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
                  javaHomeOption: JDKVersion
                  jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
                  jdkArchitectureOption: x64
                  publishJUnitResults: true
                  testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                  goals: package
                 displayName: Compile maven project
             - ${{ if contains(parameters.host, '_T4TC_') }}:        
               - task: Maven@4
                 inputs:
                  mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                  mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
                  javaHomeOption: JDKVersion
                  jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
                  jdkArchitectureOption: x64
                  publishJUnitResults: true
                  testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                  goals: package
                 displayName: Compile maven project            
             - task: CopyFiles@2
               inputs:
                 SourceFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target
                 Contents: '*.jar'
                 TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
               displayName: Stage Jar files for publishing
             - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
               inputs:
                 targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
                 artifact: Binaries
                 publishLocation: pipeline
               displayName: Publish Jar file
  - stage: Deploy_JansTool
    pool: CDaaSLinux
    jobs:
      - job: Deploy_JansTool
        variables:
          KeyVaultSubscription: P00877-KeyVault-SVC-NONPROD
          '${{ if contains(parameters.host, ''_T1_'') }}':
            defaultKeyVaultName: INGOneP00877KvT
            secretsFilter: '*'
            hosts_ini_directory_name: test
            ansible_account: ansible_ibp_test@HG_IAM_00001u7_T@ssz
            CyberAck: P00877-CyberAck-test
          '${{ if contains(parameters.host, ''_A1_'') }}':
            defaultKeyVaultName: INGOneP00877KvA
            secretsFilter: '*'
            hosts_ini_directory_name: accept
            ansible_account: ansible_ibp_acc@HG_IAM_00001u7_A@ssz
            CyberAck: P00877-CyberAck-accept
          '${{ if contains(parameters.host, ''_T4TC_'') }}':
            defaultKeyVaultName: INGOneP00877KvT
            secretsFilter: '*'
            hosts_ini_directory_name: test
            ansible_account: ansible_ibp_test@HG_IAM_00001u7_T@ssz
            CyberAck: P00877-CyberAck-test
            checkserver: true
            
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 1
            persistCredentials: true
          - task: AzureKeyVault@1
            displayName: Loading Default Azure KeyVault
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '${{ variables.KeyVaultSubscription }}'
              KeyVaultName: $(defaultKeyVaultName)
              SecretsFilter: $(secretsFilter)
              RunAsPreJob: true
          - task: CyberArkPwv@1
            displayName: PWV
            name: PWV
            inputs:
              svcConnection: '${{ variables.CyberAck }}'
              accounts: $(ansible_account)
          - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
            displayName: Replace Tokens with KeyVault Secrets
            inputs:
              rootDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/
              targetFiles: |
                **/*.yml
                **/*.ini
              keepToken: true
              enableTelemetry: false
          - task: ING-Romania.CDaaSAnsibleRolesInit.custom-build-release-task.PrepareAnsibleRuntime@0
            displayName: Prepare Ansible Runtime
            inputs:
              ansibleConfigFilePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/ansible.cfg

          - task: Ansible@0
            displayName: execute Deploy_JansToolPB.yml
            inputs:
              ansibleInterface: agentMachine
              playbookPathOnAgentMachine: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/Deploy_JansTool_PB.yml
              inventoriesAgentMachine: file
              inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/ipc/${{variables.hosts_ini_directory_name}}/hosts.ini
              args: '-vvvvv --extra-vars "host=${{parameters.host}}"'
              
          - task: Ansible@0
            displayName: execute Deploy_JansToolPB.yml
            inputs:
              ansibleInterface: agentMachine
              playbookPathOnAgentMachine: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/Deploy_JansTool_PB2.yml
              inventoriesAgentMachine: file
              inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/resources/ipc/${{variables.hosts_ini_directory_name}}/hosts.ini
              args: '-vvvvv --extra-vars "host=${{parameters.host}}"'
```

Comment: what do you use to validate the yaml?

Comment: @RupeshSA I am using the Azure  Pipeline Built-in validation feature.

Comment: Nope, It did not work, with error, "/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 61, Col: 13): Expected at least one key-value pair in the mapping"

Comment: @RupeshSA  Can you update the question and  share full  yaml sample of the issue?

Comment: @RupeshSA Are you seeing the error when using the pipeline validation feature?

Comment: yes, from the validation feature, but I have found another solution now, I am not using the "If" condition, I am using the "conditions" feature.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages

Comment: Let me know if you want the code snippet. :P

Comment: @RupeshSA If you have found the solution to solve the issue, you can add a new answer to share the solution. If you need to resolve the current issue, you can share the current code sample of the issue.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. also the error. @Kevin

Comment: @RupeshSA Thanks for your sharing. I can reproduce the same issue and have done the modification for the yaml code. You can check the update in the answer. The main issue is that your code under the if expression loses indentation

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the errors because you have not indented after your if-statements, the engine expects to run everything **one indentation in** from the if-statement if it evaluates to `true`.

Hence solving your errors for each if-statement would simply be i.e.

```yaml
- ${{ if contains(parameters.host, '_T1_') }}:  
  - task: Maven@3 # <-- One indentation in from if-statement
    # Task continues here
```

When they are currently (in your example) on the same indentation, the engine does not understand what you want to run when the if-statement evaluated to `true`, hence it is telling you it expected at least one key-pair to be found after the if-statement (one indentation in).